# Display a value from MySql on a label

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

How can I display a value from MySql on a label?

```
MySqlConnection conn = null;
string strConn = @"Server=localhost;Database=locadora;Uid=root;Pwd='';Connect Timeout=30;";
conn = new MySqlConnection(strConn);
conn.Open();
string mSQL = "SELECT cliente_codigo FROM cliente WHERE cliente_nome LIKE '%" + txt_nomepesquisa.Text"%'";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(mSQL, conn);
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
this.dgv_cliente.DataSource = dt;
```

This one shows in a Data Grid View. How can I show on a label called `lbl_cliente_codigo`?

Comment: By the way, here is an [useful read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want,

```
lbl_cliente_codigo.Text = dt.Rows[row number]["column name" | column ordinal];
```

so

for the first row and the first column (using the ordinal position) in the datatable it would be like this

```
lbl_cliente_codigo.Text = dt.Rows[0][0];
```

of if you were looping through in a for each

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    lbl_cliente_codigo.Text = row[0].ToString()
    // or
    lbl_cliente_codigo.Text = row["Column Name"].ToString()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since i don't know how your full code looks like, i will write all needed elements (my method, but many possible):

```
//put this on top under "public partial class"

    private string conn;
    MySqlConnection connect;

//make a private void which connects to database

 private void db_connection()
    {
        try
        {
            conn = "Server=127.0.0.1;Database=locadora;Uid=root;Pwd=;";
            connect = new MySqlConnection(conn);
            connect.Open();
        }

        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No connection!");
        }

     //Make private bool with MySql code

     private bool Read_Value()
    {
        db_connection();
        MySqlCommand cmdRead = new MySqlCommand(string _client);


         //I just used your code. If not right, edit

        cmdRead.CommandText = "SELECT cliente_codigo FROM cliente WHERE cliente_codigo =@_cliente_codigo AND cliente_nome LIKE '%" + txt_nomepesquisa.Text"%'";
        cmdRead.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_cliente_codigo" _client);
        cmdRead.Connection = connect;
        MySqlDataReader dbRead= cmdRead.ExecuteReader();
        if (dbRead.Read())
        {
            lbl_cliente_codigo.Text = dbRead.GetString(0);
            connect.Close();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            connect.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }

//use it in, lets say button click

//(put in button event)
string _client = lbl_cliente_codigo.text;
try
{
  bool c = Read_Value(_client);
  if(c)
  { 
     lbl_cliente_codigo.text = _client;
  }
}

catch
{
  MessageBox.Show("No connection!");
}
```

Could have errors (hope not).